# Sending parameters to Rest API for SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, angular

I have created a SQL server with a table that has data in on a server I have local access to. I have also created an "API" on that same server to get the information from the SQL server so it can be read by my angular application.

At the moment, I can read the rows in the SQL server and have them displayed in my angular application, but, I want to be able to update the SQL table from my angular app (through the API).

This is my API (`sqlserver.js`):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("msnodesqlv8");

    // config for your database
    var config = "server=servername;Database=dataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}"
    const query = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
    // connect to your database

    sql.query(config, query, (err, rows) => {
        res.send(rows)
     });
});


var server = app.listen(3097, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

I want to be able to use the query

`const query = "SELECT * from tableName WHERE ID LIKE <inputFromAngular>"`

But I am not sure how to get the parameter from angular into the `sqlserver.js`. (If I can do this then it will lead to updating the SQL Table using `SET`

In my angular app this is how I am calling the `sqlserver.js` to display the SQL table:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(
    private httpService: HttpClient
    ) { }


this.httpService.get("http://servername:3097").subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.sqlData = response;
      })
```

I have tried using `this.httpService.post()` but I wasn't sure how to get the parameters in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change you get method to send params from ui side and get params on backend side so add a server side method like

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("msnodesqlv8");
 var id = req.params.id,
    // config for your database
    var config = "server=servername;Database=dataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}"
    const query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID LIKE "+id;
    // connect to your database

    sql.query(config, query, (err, rows) => {
        res.send(rows)
     });
});
```

then on angular side

```
this.httpService.get("http://servername:3097/"+yourid).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.sqlData = response;
      })
```

**Also I would suggest you to create a root like `/yourapiname/:id` instead of `/:id` and  url on angular side should be "http://servername:3097/yourapiname"+yourid because your current root can result to confliction.**

Comment: Brilliant that was exactly what I was after. It works if I am sending a single parameter but when I try to send a JSON object it runs `[object Object]` on the server. Can i only send strings with this method?

Comment: for that you will have to create a post request.you are trying to create some record right?